# getting only the results i need in unminable API

Tags: javascript, html, api

I wanna use unminable API
like this one

```
 https://api.unminable.com/v4/address/0x9ee9e85cae8299f1f634d2306dbab94c885040a1?coin=SHIB
```

if u see when u use this URL in the browser the result is

`{"success":true,"msg":"Ok","data":{"balance":"812765.88792766","balance_payable":"812765.88792766","precision":"8","payment_threshold":"1500000","mining_fee":"1","auto":false,"enabled":true,"enabled_auto_only":false,"uuid":"85c636dd-0598-46f1-b579-72b4b5c64ae2","fresh":false,"address":"0x9ee9e85cae8299f1f634d2306dbab94c885040a1","network":"ETH","err_flags":{"payment_error":false,"missing_memo":false,"not_activated":false,"restricted":false},"chains":[{"name":"Ethereum","network":"ETH","token_standard":"ERC20","regex":"^(0x)[0-9A-Fa-f]{40}$","regex_memo":null,"is_default":true,"explorer_address":"https://etherscan.io/address/","enabled":true,"enabled_auto_only":false,"payment_threshold":"1500000","compatible":true},{"name":"Binance Smart Chain","network":"BSC","token_standard":"BEP20","regex":"^(0x)[0-9A-Fa-f]{40}$","regex_memo":null,"is_default":false,"explorer_address":"https://bscscan.com/address/","enabled":true,"enabled_auto_only":false,"payment_threshold":"250000","compatible":true},{"name":"Kucoin Community Chain","network":"KCC","token_standard":"KRC20","regex":"^(0x)[0-9A-Fa-f]{40}$","regex_memo":null,"is_default":false,"explorer_address":"https://explorer.kcc.io/en/address/","enabled":true,"enabled_auto_only":false,"payment_threshold":"250000","compatible":true}]}}`

but I only want to see the balance

"balance":"**812765.88792766**"

is there is any method to do that in HTML or Javascript WebPage?
Thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the result in an object, then access the `data.balance` property like this, and then update your html when data is fetched from the api:

Given this html:

```
<div id="balance"></div>
<button onclick="fetchDataAndUpdateHtml()">Click me</button>
```

You can fetch the data and update it like this:

```
function fetchDataAndUpdateHtml() {
    const url = 'https://api.unminable.com/v4/address/0x9ee9e85cae8299f1f634d2306dbab94c885040a1?coin=SHIB';
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
            document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML = result.data.balance));
        });
```

Comment: thanks
but how can I use it on an HTML page if u have time to tell me I really appreciate it <3

Comment: Just updated hot to use the data inside the HTML page